# Rails undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm using `simple_form` and I want to display errors to the user inside of partial. To do so I've got pretty simple form:

```
# test_result/shared/_form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for :test_results, url: url  do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <% randomize_questions.each_with_index.map do |q, i| %>
    <%= f.input "[#{i}][answer]", collection: q[:answers].map.with_index { |a, i| [a, i.to_s] }, as: :radio_buttons %>
    <%= f.input "[#{i}][id]", as: :hidden, input_html: { value: q[:id] } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

It's rendered inside of `new.html.erb` via:

```
  <%= render 'test_result/shared/form', url: test_step_one_path, randomize_questions: @randomize_questions  %>
```

Controller is also pretty standard:

```
class TestBaseController < SignupBaseController
  before_action :randomize_questions, only: %i[new create]

  def new
    @test_result = TestResult.new
  end

  def create
    @test_result = current_user.test_results.new(
      answer: test_result_params,
    )

    if @test_result.save
      redirect_to next_step_path
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

private

  def test_result_params
    params.require(:test_results).permit(question_answer_params)
  end

  def question_answer_params
    (0..@randomize_questions.length).each_with_object({}) do |i, hash|
      hash[i.to_s] = %i[id answer question]
    end
  end
```

This is one of the steps in the registration process. But I cannot display the page with this form because the below error shows up:

```
undefined method errors for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #3):
              
1 <%= simple_form_for :appropriateness_test_results, url: url  do |f| %>
2  <%= f.error_notification %>
3  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
```

Which means `f.object = nil` - did I passed something wrong? How should it look like so that I can display errors to the user?

[EDIT]

I've added `test_params` inside of controller. The `question_answer_params` will produce below hash when the user does not select anything:

```
# question_answer_params output 
{"0"=>{"id"=>"21", "answer"=>""},
 "1"=>{"id"=>"22", "answer"=>""},
 "2"=>{"id"=>"23", "answer"=>""},
 "3"=>{"id"=>"18", "answer"=>""},
 "4"=>{"id"=>"19", "answer"=>""},
 "5"=>{"id"=>"20", "answer"=>""}}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think render should be

```
  <%= render 'test_result/shared/form', url: test_step_one_path, randomize_questions: @randomize_questions, test_results: @test_result %>
```

or

form should be like

```
<%= simple_form_for @test_result, url: url  do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <% randomize_questions.each_with_index.map do |q, i| %>
    <%= f.input "[#{i}][answer]", collection: q[:answers].map.with_index { |a, i| [a, i.to_s] }, as: :radio_buttons %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If I add `test_results: @test_result` into render - nothing really changed, the same error appears. When I update the form I'm getting `undefined method [0][answer] for #<TestResult:0x00007ff20034a900>Did you mean?  answer`

Comment: Without simple_form error handling everything works well - it saves the record, displays everything properly.

Comment: Oh, nice. could'mt help sorry